# How to fill the input type = range in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit-element, input-type-range

I have to use an input type = range in my web app.
The problem is that it seems to not fill properly.

Have a look:

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular-csp.min.css" integrity="sha512-nptw3cPhphu13Dy21CXMS1ceuSy2yxpKswAfZ7bAAE2Lvh8rHXhQFOjU+sSnw4B+mEoQmKFLKOj8lmXKVk3gow==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js" integrity="sha512-7oYXeK0OxTFxndh0erL8FsjGvrl2VMDor6fVqzlLGfwOQQqTbYsGPv4ZZ15QHfSk80doyaM0ZJdvkyDcVO7KFA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="3" value="0" @change='${this.handleTableColumns}'>
```

(The function called @change hides the table column with the index equal to e.target.value).

Do you have any idea to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your range goes from 0 to 3. So you can either choose [0, 1, 2, 3]. Your slider seems to fall half between 1 and 2 and the blue line seems to select 1 as a value. Do you want to be able to select `1.5`? (Also I'm not able to manually reproduce this on Chrome 87 on Windows 10.)

Comment: No, I don't want to be able to select 1.5, I want to be able to select 0,1,2,3. I tried also to add a step='1', but nothing changed

Comment: Your code snippet works exactly how its supposed to be for me

Comment: Yes, I don't know why here it works and in local it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, I found the bug: there was a css that styled inputs in an inusual way. I changed it styling in this way only the specific input tags and not the range input tag.

This was the css rule that broke the range input. This explains also why the code snipped posted here is working. Thanks to all! Have a good day

```
.styled-input {
          padding: 4px 20px;
          margin: 0 4px;          
          font-size: 14px;
          border-radius: 2px;
          border: 1px solid;
          outline: none;
        }
```